# what does [::-1] slice for a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

For an numpy A, what does A[::-1] do?

```
A[::-1]
```

'-1' means any dimension of column?

What about 2 dots? For example, the new array doesn't change:

```
In [11]: x = np.indices((3,3))                                                                                                                                                        

In [12]: x                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[12]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])

In [13]: type(x)                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[13]: numpy.ndarray

In [14]: x[::-1]                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[14]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
```

Comment: From duplicate's top answer: `a[::-1]    # all items in the array, reversed`

Comment: That `x` is a (2,3,3) shape  (`x.shape`).  `x[::-1]` slices the first dimension, the size 2 one.  Slice notation is `start:stop:step`, here it means reverse.  The two blocks are switched in `Out[14]`.

Comment: You might want to start by experimenting with python lists.   `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `x[2:]` and `x[::2]` and `x[::-1]`.  The array indexing builds on the patterns established for lists.